# I'm having trouble getting my trigger to place a null value in a field when Account Team member is deleted. Old value stays in field on Acocunt

Tags: apex, trigger

The 2 issues I'm having is clearing the `Account` field value when the `Account Team Member` is deleted. Also, is there a way to update the `Account` field without having a user edit the `Account`?

```
trigger ADAccountTeam on Account (before update, before insert) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Account account: Trigger.new) {
        accountIds.add(Account.Id);
    }

    accountIds.remove(null);

    Map<Id, Id> accountToTeamMemberMap = new Map<Id, Id>();

    for (AccountTeamMember teamMember: [
        select UserId, AccountId
        from AccountTeamMember
        where Account.Id in :accountIds and
            TeamMemberRole = 'CJ Advertiser Account Director'
    ]) {
        accountToTeamMemberMap.put(teamMember.AccountId, teamMember.UserId);
    }

    for (Account account: trigger.new) {
        if (accountToTeamMemberMap.containsKey(Account.Id)) {
            Account.CJ_Advertiser_Account_Director__c = accountToTeamMemberMap.get(Account.Id);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The 2 issues I'm having is clearing the Account Field value when the Account Team member is deleted.  Also, is there a way to update the Account field without having a user edit the Account?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a bit confusing - you ask about clearing a field in Account when you delete an `AccountTeamMember` yet the code you posted is for insert and update of Accounts. I think you are wondering how, in the absence of triggers on `AccountTeamMember`, you can be signaled to remove/reset the custom "rollup" `Account.CJ_Advertiser_Account_Director__c`.

There is an [Idea to support triggers on AccountTeamMember](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YR8IAAW). Vote it up.  I'll quote one commenter, Mark Ross, who said

```
I nearly cried when I found out this didn't exist already
```

So, there are a couple of workarounds

**Scheduled Job**

Write a scheduled job that runs (daily/hourly/every x mins) and looks for deleted AccountTeamMembers, then signals the Account via setting a custom field `is_ready_for_custom_atm_rollup__c` to true. Your Account before update trigger executes and queries all children ATM, resets the `CJ_Advertiser_Account_Director__c` to what it should be and then clears `is_ready_for_custom_atm_rollup__c`

**VF page**
If field `CJ_Advertiser_Account_Director__c` is not needed for reporting, but only to show users when they view an Account, you can dynamically rollup the field via a VF page inserted on your Account page layout